# How to find all places in a project, where overridden ~= is used?

Tags: swift, xcode, switch-statement, overriding

```
extension String {
    static func ~= (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: rhs) else { return false }
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: lhs.utf16.count)
        return regex.firstMatch(in: lhs, options: [], range: range) != nil
    }
}
```

I can’t figure out a way to find all places in a project, where this overridden function is used.
`Cmd+Ctrl+Shift+H` doesn’t work in this case for some reason.

You can say: “Just search for `~=` symbols in the codebase”.
But `~=` is also ***implicitly*** used for evaluation of `switch-case` operators.

Use case:
Let’s say I want to change the logic of the `~=` function (and I really do). And I know for sure, that I also have to fix the code in places, where this function is used. So I need to find all the `switch-cases` where it is used. Otherwise these `switch-cases` will become work incorrectly (and the compiler will not show any warnings).

P. S.
As an example of a solution: to search for all the `switch` appearance in the codebase and among them look only for `switch String`/`case String`. That would be exactly what I need.
The only problem with this approach: it will take me hours (if not days)

Comment: Your "Use case" paragraph indicates that you are setting yourself up for a big mess. You could get it all fixed now and then sometime down the road you forget about the issue and introduce new code that has the same issue as the code you want to search for now. But this time you don't realize that it's an issue and you have some subtle bug you can't find. Sounds like you need to override a different operator with your new special functionality so you don't break other code. Something to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you were to deprecate the override? Then you just have to look through your compiler warnings.

```
extension String {
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Found it")
    static func ~= (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: rhs) else { return false }
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: lhs.utf16.count)
        return regex.firstMatch(in: lhs, options: [], range: range) != nil
    }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly a kind of solution I was looking for! Thank you!